# how to get elements of euclidean division in C (no the remainder)

Tags: c

alright. I have the Euclidean division like this : **a = b * q + r**

I know that to get r, I can do the modulo : `a % b`

but how do I get q ? `//` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `/` rather than `//`?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about elementary mathematics.

Comment: Actually, it's about C syntax

Comment: Floor division operator  `//` is in Python, but not in C.

Comment: Note that if `a` or `q` are negative, you'll need to define exactly what behaviour you need in order to give a precise answer (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Remainder_calculation_for_the_modulo_operation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a and b are integers, just use integer division, `/`.

Comment: pretty simple indeed. Thanks.

Comment: @David天宇Wong: Do not rely on this answer if the numbers might be negative until you investigate the differences between C’s division and remainder and the results you want when the numbers are negative. The C remainder operator is notorious for differing from what mathematicians would prefer in some uses.

Comment: The `/` operator in C always rounds towards zero. Thus, this is not the Euclidean division. It only behaves the same way for non-negative integers.

Comment: Integer division in C is **NOT** Euclidean division.

Answer (score 3):

Using [Euclidean division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division)

```
If a = 7 and b = 3, then q = 2 and r = 1, since 7 = 3 × 2 + 1.
If a = 7 and b = −3, then q = −2 and r = 1, since 7 = −3 × (−2) + 1.
If a = −7 and b = 3, then q = −3 and r = 2, since −7 = 3 × (−3) + 2.
If a = −7 and b = −3, then q = 3 and r = 2, since −7 = −3 × 3 + 2.
```

Likely a more simple solution is available.

```
int Ediv(int a, int b) {
  printf("a:%2d / b:%2d = ", a,b);
  int r = a % b;
  if (r < 0) r += abs(b);
  printf("r:%2d ", r);
  return (a - r) / b;
}

void Etest() {
  printf("q:%2d\n", Ediv(7,3));
  printf("q:%2d\n", Ediv(7,-3));
  printf("q:%2d\n", Ediv(-7,3));
  printf("q:%2d\n", Ediv(-7,-3));
}

a: 7 / b: 3 = r: 1 q: 2
a: 7 / b:-3 = r: 1 q:-2
a:-7 / b: 3 = r: 2 q:-3
a:-7 / b:-3 = r: 2 q: 3
```

OP asserts "I know that to get `r`, I can do the modulo : `a % b`".  This fails when `a` is negative.

Further, `%` is the "remainder operator".  In C, the difference between Euclidean remainder and modulo occurs when `a` is negative.  [Remainder calculation for the modulo operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Remainder_calculation_for_the_modulo_operation)

Answer (score 1):

chux's answer is a good one, as it's the one that correctly understands the question (unlike the accepted one). Daan Leijen's [*Division and Modulus for Computer Scientists*](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/division-and-modulus-for-computer-scientists/) also provides an algorithm with proof:

```
/* Euclidean quotient */
long quoE(long numer, long denom) {
  /* The C99 and C++11 languages define both of these as truncating. */
  long q = numer / denom;
  long r = numer % denom;
  if (r < 0) {
    if (denom > 0)
      q = q - 1; // r = r + denom;
    else {
      q = q + 1; // r = r - denom;
  }
  return q;
}
```

This one is trivially equivalent to chux's algorithm. It looks a bit more verbose, but it might take one fewer `div` instruction on x86, as the instruction performs a "divmod" -- returning q and r at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Take an example:

```
7 = 3*2 + 1
```

2 (`q`) can be obtained by `7/3`, i.e, `a/b = q`.